# How to understand scope within generators?

Tags: python, scope, generator

I seem to misunderstand variable scope within generators. Why do the following two results differ? (Note the second use of `tuple` when producing the second result.)

```
def f(x): return x

result1 = tuple(itertools.chain(*((f(val) for _ in range(2)) for val in (1,2,3))))

result2 = tuple(itertools.chain(*(tuple(f(val) for _ in range(2)) for val in (1,2,3))))

print(result1==result2) # False; why?
```

Comment: It might be more instructive if you actually printed the values of `result1` and `result2`, rather than just comparing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, scope is working like it always works. Generators just create a local, enclosing scope, just like a function. Essentially, you are creating a closure over `val`, and in Python, closures are lexically-scoped and late-binding, i.e., their value is evaluated at the point of executing not definition.

The difference between the two is *when* the outer generator get's iterated over versus the inner generator. In your first example, the outer generator is iterated completely before any of the inner generators are, in the second example, `tuple` forces them to be evaluated in-tandem.

The problem is that when you use `*` argument splatting, it *immediately* evaluates your generator (the outer one), however, the inner generator isn't evaluated yet, but it is closed over `val`, but `val = 3` at the end of the first generator.

But, in your second example,

```
(tuple(f(val) for _ in range(2)) for val in (1,2,3)))
```

The inner call to `tuple` forces `f` to be called when `val` is `1`, `2`, and `3`, and thus, `f` captures those values.

So, consider the following nested generator, and two different ways of iterating over them:

```
>>> def gen():
...     for i in range(3):
...         yield (i for _ in range(2))
...
>>> data = list(gen()) # essentially what you are doing with the splatting
>>> for item in data:
...     print(list(item))
...
[2, 2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2]
>>> for item in gen():
...     print(list(item))
...
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
>>>
```

And finally, this should also be informative:

```
>>> gs = []
>>> for item in gen():
...     gs.append(item)
...
>>> gs
[<generator object gen.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x1041ceba0>, <generator object gen.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x1041cecf0>, <generator object gen.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x1041fc200>]
>>> [list(g) for g in gs]
[[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

Again, you have to think of what the closure value will be *when* it actually is evaluated, in the above case, since I've already iterated over the outer generator, so `i` is `2`, and simply appended the inner generators to another list, *and then* I evaluate the inner generators, they will see the value of `i` as `2`, because that is what it is.

To reiterate, this occurs because `*` splatting *force* the generator to be iterated over. use `chain.from_iterable` instead and you'll get `True` for your `result1 == result2`.